# When is $\oint_C vdz=\oint_C\overline vd\overline z$?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration

Integrals of the type

$$\oint_C(vdz-\overline vd\overline z)$$

where the bar denotes complex conjugation, come up in certain areas of physics, especially conformal field theory, where this comes from integrating a current conservation equation in the complex plane, and $C$ is typically the boundary of some region. Here $v$ and $\overline v$ are smooth, but are not in general required to be holomorphic. The vanishing of this integral is often important.

So my question is, if we have some closed contour $C$, are there any general theorems on when these integrals will vanish? i.e. when

$$\oint_C vdz=\oint_C\overline vd\overline z$$

Comment: Are we to understand that $\overline{v}$ is the complex conjugate of $v$?  I ask since that may not be the usual notation in physics, although it is in mathematics.

Comment: yes, just usual notation here, bar denotes conjugate

I only gave that as a background because if I asked with no context I'd normally get someone asking why I cared in the first place or something

Answer (score 1):

The integral equals

$$\oint_{\partial \Omega}(v\:dz-\bar{v}\:d\bar{z}) = 2i\operatorname{Im}\left\{\oint_{\partial \Omega}v\:dz\right\}$$

We can take this further see that the equation we need to analyze is

$$2i\operatorname{Im}\left\{\oint_{\partial \Omega}v\:dz\right\} = 4i\operatorname{Re}\left\{\iint\limits_{\Omega}\frac{\partial v}{\partial \bar{z}}\:dx\wedge dy\right\}=0$$

If we assert that the quantity is zero for all $\Omega \subset \Bbb{C}$ we get that the functions in the kernel of the original integral must obey

$$\operatorname{Re}\left\{\frac{\partial v}{\partial \bar{z}}\right\}=0$$

Holomorphic functions are a subset of this kernel since for $v$ holomorphic the partial derivative would be zero exactly.

Comment: In this case, there is nothing forcing this to be true for an arbitrary contour. Or is this just intended as an extra comment in that particular case?

Comment: @Hobbyist you literally cannot say anything else without that assumption since these behave more like arbitrary real functions than complex functions with nice properties. There is nothing else special or interesting about these functions (other than their physical interpretations)